# How do I consolidate two workbooks with overlapping data as well as new data?

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I wrote a macro that takes order lines from one spreadsheet, subtotals them, and then transfers the order totals into a master tracker.  There are then columns and fields in the master tracker that need to be updated manually.

I have been informed that the macro will no longer only reference the spreadsheet with order lines, but will need to reference the tracker from the previous day (the most up-to-date) version of the tracker and match the order lines up with that.  The cells that are updated manually need to stay aligned with the order they refer to.

The problem I am facing is the merging of the spreadsheets.  The spreadsheet with the order lines will contain the orders already on the master tracker, as well as some new orders.  I sort the order lines based on the order number, which is a combination of letters and numbers.  Because of this, I can't just lock the cells and add the new orders to the bottom (a new demo order will be sorted above the previously existing service order, pushing the service orders down and throwing off any of the data in the locked cells).

Is there a way maintain the data in each row of the tracker, while still inserting and adding new order details to the master tracker?

Here is the macro as-is (no manual entry fields mentioned):

```
Sub Subtotal()
'
' Subtotal Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+S
'
' Macro can handle 7500 order lines
'                  1000 orders
'
' Must update File Name and File Location should anything change
'
Range("A1:X7500").Select
Range("M7").Activate
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = "Tracker"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracker").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracker").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B2:B5000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracker").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:X7500")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(20), _
    Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

Dim saved As String
Dim start As Integer
Dim count As Integer
start = 2
saved = Cells(start, 2).Value

Dim i As Integer
For i = (start + 1) To 7500
    Dim c As String
    c = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Value

    If IsEmpty(c) Then
        Exit For
    End If

    If Not saved = c Then
        Dim tmp As Range
        Set tmp = Range(Cells(start, 5), Cells(i - 1, 5))
        Dim desc As Range
        Set desc = Range(Cells(start, 7), Cells(i - 1, 7))
        Dim line As Range
        Set line = Range(Cells(start, 6), Cells(i - 1, 6))

        count = 0

        If Not tmp.Find("3000") Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "3000"
            count = count + 1

            If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If

        End If

        If Not tmp.Find("4000") Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "4000"
            Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
            count = count + 1

        End If

        If Not tmp.Find("5000 CASE") Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "5000 Case"
            count = count + 1

            If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If

        End If

        If Not tmp.Find("5000 STAIN") Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "5000 Stain"
            count = count + 1

            If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If

        End If

        If Not tmp.Find("SPECIALTY") Is Nothing Then
            Dim count2 As Integer
            count2 = 0

            If Not line.Find("3000") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "3000"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("3500FC") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "3000"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("3700") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "3000"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("ECP") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "5000 Stain"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("3700C") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "5000 Stain"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("AS-") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "3000"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("CUSTOM CART") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "4000 Carts"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("ET-4000") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "4000 Carts"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("3700VV") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "4000 Carts"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If Not line.Find("4700SC") Is Nothing Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "4000 Carts"
                count2 = count2 + 1

                If Not desc.Find("Custom") Is Nothing Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Custom"
                Else: Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
                End If
            End If

            If count2 > 1 Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "Mixed"
            End If
            count = count + 1

        End If

        If Not tmp.Find("SMALL CART") Is Nothing Then

            count = count + 1
            Dim cartRow As Integer
            cartRow = tmp.Find("SMALL CART").Row

            If Not InStr(Cells(cartRow, 6).Text, "7") = 1 Then
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "Small Cart"
                Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
            Else
                Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "7000 Series"
                Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
            End If

        End If

        If count = 0 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "Other"
            Range(Cells(i, 6), Cells(i, 6)).Value = "Standard"
        End If

        If count > 1 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Value = "Mixed"
        End If

        If Range(Cells(i, 20), Cells(i, 20)).Value > 10000 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5)).Value = "Critical"
        Else
            Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5)).Value = "Non Critical"
        End If

        Range(Cells(i, 10), Cells(i, 10)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 4), Cells(i - 1, 4)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 7)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 13), Cells(i - 1, 13)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 14), Cells(i, 14)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 14), Cells(i - 1, 14)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 13), Cells(i, 13)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 15), Cells(i - 1, 15)).Value
        Range(Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, 16)).Value = Range(Cells(i - 1, 16), Cells(i - 1, 16)).Value

        ' Ignore the totals rows by incrementing past it
        i = i + 1
        start = i
        saved = Range(Cells(start, 2), Cells(start, 2)).Value
    End If
Next i

' Bring Total rows from Tracker sheet into Master Tracker Workbook
' Paste into Sheet 2 first in order to only get total rows
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
Range("B4:W4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("S1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("G1:G700")

' Set Aging Since Order Placement formula
Range("H1").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(A1), """", TODAY() - F1)"
Range("H1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H1:H1011"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("H1:H1011").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("A1:I1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

' File Location
ChDir "C:\Users\etc."

' File Name
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\etc."
Sheets("Master Tracker").Select
Range("B11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

' Set the segment class for each order
' Formula goes to row 1011 to allow for 1000 orders
Range("D11").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B11), """", IF(Q11=DATE(2000,1,1), ""UnSchd"",  ""Scheduled""))"
Range("D11").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D11:D1011"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B11").Select

' Bring over remaining Dates
Windows("ORDER_LINE_SHEET").Activate
Range("L1:M1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MASTER_TRACKER_WORKBOOK").Activate
Range("L11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("ORDER_LINE_SHEET").Activate
Range("O1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MASTER_TRACKER_WORKBOOK").Activate
Range("Q11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("J:J").WrapText = True
Range("B11").Select
End Sub
```

This will be helpful in converting the new order lines into order totals but I cannot overwrite the cells that have been manually updated and cannot have those cells aligned with the wrong order row.  Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: It would probably be easier to have a single worksheet of all of the orders and build the tracker directly from that (i.e. with no need to reference any previous days trackers). Updating would be a case of adding the new orders to the end of the orders worksheet and building a new tracker. Trying to do an incremental update when much of the underlying detail has been summarised away is unlikely to be straightforward

Comment: @barrowc Thanks.  Now that I've had some time away from my desk and could think clearly, I think I will bring the tracker spreadsheet and the new update into the same workbook, separate sheets, and throw a for loop together to check the daily report order numbers against the existing tracker spreadsheet.